# Licensing, how to?

Tags: licensing, third-party-libraries

I'm currently developing an application that has quite a few dependencies.

Now I want to release the code as open-source under the WTFPL (Do What the Fuck You Want to Public License).

Of course this only applies to **my** code, not that of any dependency. How would I go about this?

I pull in my dependencies via an automatic build tool (sbt in that case).

More concretely:

Assume I'm pulling in lwjgl (http://www.lwjgl.org/) and another third-party-library that consists only of one file and has the copyright at the top of it.

Now how would I do this legally correctly? Just add the license to the code as it's "**obvious**" what's my code and what's not? Or...

I'm not sure if there is a license file in the (automatically pulled down) dependencies. Actually I just had a look into my `.ivy2` folder and I can't find a license for e.g. lwjgl

Any ideas? I'm sorry, if (and it probably has) this has been covered before, but I want to make sure I'm doing this right and I couldn't find my specific question(s) [yes, I search before I post ;)]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure all the licenses of your dependencies allow you to share their libraries to your customers. You might need to credit the authors anywhere, it's all written down in the licenses.

If you have the permission, you also need to provide the licenses of the libraries in your product. If you don't have the permission, you should contact the authors of the libraries and try to buy it, so you can use it in your product. I bet this is not required, as your software is not for commecial use.

Comment: But the software may be for commercial use (as it's WTFPL licensed)... do I really need to do this, even if I just pull in dependencies?

Comment: If your software is commercial use, then you have to get commecial license for every dependencies! Check the licenses of your dependencies, some allow to use their products for commecial use, too, some not! If not, you need a commecial use license! If you buy it, you usualy don't need to provide the license to your customers.

Comment: modiX I only use software that is open source and free to use, so there should be no problem with that. I just want to open source my code that is dependant on lwjgl to some extent.